# when use nginx Cache-Control , nginx wont serve cached data

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config, nginx-location

i have a config for my django app deployment with nginx
and want to cache some of data

```
server {
listen 80 default_server;
listen [::]:80 default_server;

root /app/;

location / {
    proxy_pass http://landing_page;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_redirect off;
}


location /static/ {
    alias  /app/staticfiles/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ ;
}

location /media/ {
    alias  /app/media/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ ;
}

location ~* \.(svg|ico|woff|woff2|ttf)$ {
    expires 1M;
    add_header Cache-Control "public";
}}
```

when i remove cache control from config , nginx work properly and serve data like *.svg but when i enable it cached file wont serve

Comment: So it will return HTTP 404, right ? Or you mean something else by `wont serve` ?

Comment: @IVOGELOV  it return 404.

Comment: Check the nginX error log. If there is nothing - you should run nginX with debug enabled http://nginx.org/en/docs/debugging_log.html

Comment: @IVOGELOV when i remove cache section from config, nginx work properly and find file like *.svg but when use cache section it return 404

Comment: The debug log will tell you exactly why nginX returns 404. You can also try removing the trailing slash from `root` and `location` statements.